# How to make a disk image and restore to another, the hardware between the servers are the same

Tags: backup

Currently there is an issue happening on the production environment and not happening in dev. so I would like to recreate it in dev by creating a image of prod and restore it in dev. the hardware are the same as well as the RAID. My question is 
a. what the best tool to use to do that?
b. when creating the image, does it require any downtime?
c. I presume that i need to do some configuration changes once the restore is done?
d. after the restore, would the logic/physical mount be eased?

Plus I am new to Ubuntu, have tried tar way to do. it seems that it caused lots of issues. I have gave up on that due to time limitation.

Thank you so much.

Bing

Comment: use dd command to do it.
Example : 

# dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/tmp/backup_of_boot

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or ghost for Linux [G4L](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/).

I advise you to use CloneZilla: It's cloning software similar to True Image and Norton Ghost, and you don't really should care about mountings and such things since you'll not need to do so when a cone success.

CloneZilla has one limitation that it can't clone larger to smaller disk [easily](https://serverfault.com/questions/568227/prepare-a-disk-to-be-imaged-by-clonezilla-for-use-on-smaller-disks) but since you have the same hardware and same size of storage, there will be no problems.

Comment: It is possible if you [edit the `sda-pt.parted` file](https://serverfault.com/questions/568227/prepare-a-disk-to-be-imaged-by-clonezilla-for-use-on-smaller-disks)